# Livesync is not working properly in CLI using nativescript

Tags: nativescript

Livesync is not working properly. Every time I modify the js,xml or css, it's redeploying the code into devices instead of applying the changes. How we can resolve this issue?

I have used these commands:

```
tns run android --emulator --watch
tns livesync android --emulator --watch
```

Comment: I have had an issue where I had to kill the whole process and emulator in order to get the livesync to work properly again. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes @Jarvis,i have tried but didn't get the solution.

Comment: Have you unplugged the devices and then attempted to `tns livesync android --watch --emulator`? I'm assuming you have... just trying to offer another thought.

Answer (score 1):

Hello to SO and NativeScript!

Which version of NativeScript are you using!? (check with `tns --version`).A similar issue was present with earlier versions and after update to 2.2.* it should be live syncing as expected. Also under what platform you ar encountering this issue (iOS or Android) and under what environment (Windows, Mac OS or other OS)

You can skip -emulator and  use this to start on emulator (if Genymotion you should start the emulator manually before that)

```
tns livesync --watch android
```

Comment: Hi Nick, i'm using 2.2.1 version on windows.

Comment: If your project is TypeScript notice that only changes made in *.ts files will be reflected (the *.js files are transpiled after the change in *.ts file).

Comment: However changes in XML and CSS files should work as expected

Comment: I'm using only javascript and xml

Comment: I have originally posted the same question for 2.1.* and I still cannot use --watch in 2.2.* , it seems to get confused after I get my first JS console error